# R API call fails due to certificate chain issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: r, api, httr

I'm just starting to get my feet wet in the API waters, and I'm trying to follow along the "Send a simple request" section at [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/api-packages.html). When executing

```
github_api <- function(path) {
  url <- modify_url("https://api.github.com", path = path)
  GET(url)
}

resp <- github_api("/repos/hadley/httr")
```

I get the following error message:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :    schannel:
> next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT
> (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that
> is not trusted.

I'm getting similar error messages for most API calls I try to make on my machine, although the call

```
GET("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")
```

taken from [this link](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/r-api-tutorial/) happily returns data without issue. Searching google for the error message returns a lot of posts unrelated to R specifically and I'm having trouble determining what troubleshooting steps I can take.

**Update**

I have tested the call on another machine with success, so there is some setting/configuration/firewall impediment on my main machine which is preventing me from making some, but not all, API calls. This may be related to [this issue](https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/654). Is there a way to determine the root cause here and apply a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using a forward proxy which allows my machine to reach sites outside my corporate firewall as follows (I've obscured the url and port for obvious reasons):

```
proxy <- use_proxy( url = "http://myproxy"
                   ,port = 9999
                   ,auth = "basic")
github_api <- function(path) {
  url <- modify_url("https://api.github.com", path = path)
  GET(url, proxy)
}

resp <- github_api("/repos/hadley/httr")
```

Hopefully such a forward proxy exists for anyone else facing this issue.